# Changing multiple date formats in a column

Tags: r

I have a column of a data frame where some dates are formatted as

```
"2015-06-04"
```

and other dates as

```
"Thu Jun 04 15:12:10 2015"
```

Is there a way to match formatting and then add in a `strptime()`?

I tried using

```
for (i in 1:length(d1)){
  if((d1[i]) !=format("%Y-%m-%d")){
   d1[i]<- as.Date(strptime(d1[i], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))
  }
}
```

Where `d1` is my list of dates.

Comment: You could probably create an index using something like `grepl("[A-Za-z]", d1)` and then convert all of these dates to the desired format at once without any `for` loop.

Comment: You may also check `lubridate::parse_date_time` and the `orders` arguments. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463523/convert-variable-with-mixed-date-formats-to-one-format-in-r/25463927#25463927) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551343/convert-many-formats-of-dates-to-one-standard-format-in-r/24551645#24551645)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Still a bit new, and what you're suggesting gets me in the right direction, cause I'm getting the list of trues and falses. I'm just not making the connection between that and the if-then statement to actually do the replacing. Any tips?

Comment: You don't need any if statement, all you need to do is `indx <- grepl("[A-Za-z]", d1) ; d1[indx] <- as.Date(strptime(d1[indx], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))`.

Comment: What is the class of `d1`?

Comment: Tried adding `d1[indx] <- as.Date(strptime(d1[indx==TRUE], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))` and that got `NA`s where applicable at least.

Comment: Does `as.Date(strptime("Thu Jun 04 15:12:10 2015", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))` works on your system?

Comment: 1)Class of d1 is currently showing as Factor w/ 10 Levels.
2) yes that works. Will try changing to strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79691/discussion-between-gregdelima-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 0):

@David Arenburg final solve here:

`indx <- grepl("[A-Za-z]", d1) ; 
d1[indx] <- as.character(as.Date(strptime(d1[indx], format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")))`